# iOS 7 dynamically change speech bubble color in messages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

Trying to figure out how to incorporate this effect into my app.

It is essentially the adjustment of the colors in the speech bubbles when the user scrolls, as seen in the messages app in iOS 7.

The bubbles close to the top of the screen are light blue, the bubbles towards the bottom are darker.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? It's not clear if you don't know how to change the color, or how you can use the effect in your app, or something else.

Comment: You will be animating (changing the background color) as the tableview scroll position goes up or down.. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Actually sorry for being so vague. My app essentially has a list view with individual cells that each have a random background color.These cells contain text and potentially photos (if the user uploads one) and I am only wanting to change the color of the cell background for each as a user scrolls.

Comment: I havent been able to find anything about this online and was hoping there was an in depth article somewhere about this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a gradient on your views. Set the start and end color's intensity according to the view's position in the scroll view's superview (using `convertRect:toView:`). As your scrollview scrolls, update the visible bubbles' background colors according to their current position. An optimization is to only update the views which are visible. Using a table or collection view can help you with that. It's a simple yet effective effect.